# MS Exchange in Gnome Online Accounts Not Syncing

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, evolution, calendar, ms-exchange

I have added OwnCloud, Google, and Exchange in Gnome Online Accounts.  OwnCloud and Google are working as expected, but the Exchange account is not syncing anything (calendar, contacts, etc.).  Under Antergos, I have used this Exchange account in Gnome Online Accounts without issues and all syncs as expected.  I have tried keeping Evolution open while adding the account as I have seen recommended elsewhere, but this had no effect.

Running `journalctl`, I can see the following error - the server name I have entered in GOA is like "exch.exampledomain.com", not like "autodiscover.exch.exampledomain.com":  `gnome-control-center.desktop[8150]: (gnome-control-center:8150): GoaBackend-WARNING **: goa_ews_client_autodiscover() failed: 2 — Error resolving 'autodiscover.exch.exampledomain.com': Name or service not known`

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 with kernel 4.13.5-041305-generic.

Thanks in advance for any insight you might have.

UPDATE:  I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 on another machine, and have the same issue.

Comment: You should state what version of Ubuntu you're using...

Comment: You are correct.  Updated.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot be of much help, however, I tested it in a VM and here is what I found: I have this setup in my installation of Fedora 26 and am very sure that it also worked in F 25. But I cannot get this to work on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, 17.04 nor 17.10 current daily. In Fedora I just enter my account details and server URL and my account with all the data appears in Evolution, Gnome Contacts and Gnome Calender. In Ubuntu the account appears nowhere and it doesn't seem to sync anything. Maybe this is an Ubuntu bug related to their own online accounts stuff?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was resolved by installing the evolution-ews package.  A reboot was required after installation.

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

Comment: Still resolves issue on Ubuntu 19.10.
Didn't need to reboot the system. Restart of evolution was enough for me